# Strange JavaScript behaviour with window.location.href and program flow

Tags: javascript, redirect, location-href

I have an index site which checks if a cookie exists and if it has the value `EN`. If so it should redirect to an English `index.shtml`. Otherwise or if there is no (English) cookie, it should redirect to the German next page:

```
if (document.cookie)  {
    var cookieValue = document.cookie;
    if (cookieValue.indexOf("MYCOOKIE=EN") > -1)  {
        window.location.href="en/index.shtml";
    }
}
window.location.href="kategorien/hauptkategorie.shtml";
```

Now something very strange happens: The English cookie exists (I checked `cookieValue` with JavaScript alert and it shows `EN`), but even though the href inside the `if` won't be executed but the 2nd href will be executed. Why is this so?

When I add 2 `else`s, it works like expected:

```
if (document.cookie)  {
     var cookieValue = document.cookie;
     if (cookieValue.indexOf("MYCOOKIE=EN") > -1)  {
         window.location.href="en/index.shtml";
     }
     else  {
         window.location.href="kategorien/hauptkategorie.shtml";
     }
}
else  {
     window.location.href="kategorien/hauptkategorie.shtml";
}
```

Why is this so that it redirects to `hauptkategorie.shtml` if I leave the `else`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a normal Javascript statement after the `if`.

There is nothing telling that statement not to run, unless you put it in an `else`.

Navigating to a new page does not terminate execution of the current page until the new page actually loads.

Comment: So does that mean, that window.localtion.href doesn't redirect immediately?

Comment: Correct; it does not terminate execution.  You can continue using the previous page for quite a while if the new page is on a slow server.

Comment: It is actually up to the browser to decide when the redirect occurs. So the browser can easily delay it as long as it wants to finish the script execution; meaning that you shouldn’t rely on anything there.

Answer (score 3):

Probably both `window.location.href` statements execute, giving you unexpected results. Try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if (document.cookie && document.cookie.indexOf("MYCOOKIE=EN") > -1)  {
    window.location.href="en/index.shtml";  
}
else {
    window.location.href="kategorien/hauptkategorie.shtml";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Be aware this code doesn't check for `someOtherMYCOOKIE=EN` cases.